Is it possible to specify address for deployed contract in Hardhat tests?
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

describe('One to one Swap', function () {
  it('Should be able to swap tokens', async function () {
    const address = "...";
    const Token0 = await ethers.deployContract('ERC20Token', ['Token0', 'TKN0', 6, 10000]);
    const token0 = await Token0.waitForDeployment();
    // Attach address ???
});
});

I would like to use real addresses in Contract test to make things less confusing. Is this supported?
